# Зуммирование, шрифты и Firefox

Tags: css, веб-программирование, шрифты, firefox

Текст небольшого размера, допустим 12px занимает на Opera/Chrome 80 пикселей в ширину. И в пределах зума 50%-500% ширина меняется только в пределах сотых/тысячных. В firefox эта ширина постоянно прыгает, причем даже если постоянно увеличивать зум, это может быть сначала 90, а потом 75, потом снова 90. И это работает только при небольших значениях размера. Кто-то сталкивался?
Спасибо.

```
<div style="font-family: 12px; font-family: Verdana; display: inline-block;">Новое решение</div>
```

Firefox:

- 100% - 101px;
- 110% - 96px
- 120% - 92px;
- 90% - 101px
- 80% - 112px;

Comment: добавьте [mcve]

Comment: По поводу размера шрифта нельзя делать вообще никаких предположений, он может скакать в любую сторону в зависимости от браузера, ос, установленных расширений, стабильности интернета, настроек системы, установленных библиотек, параметров монитора, фазы луны, положения звёзд на небе, левой пятки юзера

Comment: Сам знаю, но заказчика это не устроит. Фиксировать ширину тоже не хотелось бы. У меня подозрение что это проблема стандартных шрифтов на FF/Gecko, буду тестировать пока с импортируемыми

Comment: Сделал сниппет с автовыводом размера для удобства тыкания https://jsfiddle.net/ft8tkwzt/

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась после импорта другого шрифта. Видимо со стандартными семействами беда.

Comment: Но не спешите радоваться: я юзал одинаковый Roboto с Google Fonts, так в IE11 фраза с ним была на пять пикселей длиннее, чем в Firefox, и не влезал в блок по ширине)